# Open the object location from find

Tags: finder

I used Spotlight to look for `Atari800MacX` to upgrade it. It shows me it is located in a folder called Games.

Well, where is this Games folder? No idea. Spotlighting "games" shows other folders called games, but not the one I'm looking for, and I'm not sure where any of these other ones are either.

Right-click does nothing, you can't *select* objects in the results (only open them)... is there any way to open the folder or otherwise figure out where the heck it is?

Comment: If you type "Atari800Mac" without pressing Enter and wait a few seconds, don't you get an option to open in Finder?

Comment: With Spotlight you mean the search triggered by Cmd-Space, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight is good for finding things but for whatever reason lousy at telling you *where* those things are, as you have discovered.

**But** you can still do a spotlight search in the Finder. Just open a new Finder window and type your search term into the search field in the upper right side of the Finder window.

Once you have located the file/folder you want it will show the path to it at the bottom of the Finder window.

If you hold the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key down while clicking the mouse on the title bar (where it displays the path again) it will give you a pop-up menu that gives you a graphical hierarchy of *exactly* where that file/folder is.

Comment: Enter a string in Spotlight and press Cmd-R to open the folder in Finder

Comment: Hey @nohillside never knew that, thx!

Comment: https://support.apple.com/de-ch/guide/mac-help/mh26783/mac, you may need to switch the language.

Comment: @nohillside Type in spotlight, hit cmd+enter and get the file in the folder

Comment: @nohillside - yeah, that's the easiest solution!